# Defining limits of nested \foreach loop by a variable

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw adjacent columns of boxes of heights decremented by 1 from left to right used nested \foreach loops in tikz.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,0.25,...,4.75}
{
\foreach \y in {-4,-3.75,...,0.75 - \x}
\filldraw[draw=black, fill=blue, opacity=0.2] (0, \y) rectangle (0.25, \y + 0.25);
}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Since each column should have 1 less box than the one to its left, I need to change the limits of the \foreach \y loop based on what \x is. But this syntax apparently isn't correct, and I have no idea how to make it accept an expression involving \x.

I also don't understand why the opacity argument of the \filldraw command is ignored.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I'm getting an undefined control sequence error.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it should be `\fpeval{...}`. To ensure we are on the same page, you should type in `\foreach \y in {-4,-3.75,...,\ fpeval{0.75 - \x}}`.

Comment: Yes. It doesn't seem to recognize the \fpeval command. Is this from the fp package?

Comment: I honestly don't know where it is exactly defined in but it is in the recent LaTeX distributions by default (don't quote me but I think starting from Jan 2021). I tried multiple times to find where it was created but couldn't. It wasn't mentioned in `texdoc interface3` nor `texdoc source3`.

Comment: Does that answer you question?

Comment: @M.AlJumaily PGF is perfectly able to do the calculation. I don't know what the introduction of `\fpeval` would achieve. The problem isn't doing the calculation. It's that the OP's example tries to do it too late. Basically, the final term of the series of values to which `\y` is set has to be expanded before the loop is set up.

Comment: When you ask a question, don't say you get errors or it doesn't work. That's not useful. Always report the exact error message you get. If you get multiple errors, report the first one. Once you're had one error, more errors are expected, so the subsequent ones don't tell you much. There is an exception to this. Sometimes the second error is the meaningful one. So report that, too, if you're not sure.

Comment: @cfr, You are correct in the sense that PGF could do the calculations. The thought was that, in general, `\fpeval{...}` could be used in any document without the need to import packages. I see you prefer to keep using what PGF offers, which is more appropriate in this case.

Comment: @M.AlJumaily But the code you proposed can't work. It doesn't matter whether it's a pgfmath expression or `\fpeval` or something else. `\foreach \y in {-4,-3.75,...,\ fpeval{0.75 - \x}}` won't work. Try it for yourself. It's not a question of my preferring what PGF offers. Note that substituting `\pgfmath...` for `\fpeval...` has just the same problem. No such solution could answer the OP's question because it reproduces the problem in the original code.

Comment: @cfr, yes, correct. My comment was to help out evaluating the expression, not solve the issue.

Comment: Just in case you don't actually need opacity but just less intense colors, you can use `xcolor`'s `!` syntax inside TikZ: `fill=blue!20`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the last term in the set `{-4,...,0.75-\x}` to be evaluated before the code tries to read it in setting up the loop. There are different ways to do this. One is to use pgf's `evaluate` option,

```
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \k using 0.75-\i] in {0,0.25,...,4.75}
{
  \foreach \j in {-4,-3.75,...,\k}
    \filldraw[draw=black, fill=blue,opacity=0.2] (0,\j) rectangle (0.25,\j+0.25);
}
```

This results in the following image.

[image: graduated blues]

I'm not quite sure what the result is meant to look like. The `opacity=.2` *is* effective, but if you layer enough blobs of 20% opacity one on top of another, they no longer look opaque.
To see this, try shifting the blocks rather than painting them one on top of another each time you iterate through the loop. For example,

```
  \foreach \j in {-4,-3.75,...,\k}
    \filldraw[draw=black, fill=blue,opacity=0.2] (\i,\j) rectangle (\i+0.25,\j+0.25);
```

produces

[image: graduated steps of non-graduated blue]

Or perhaps you'd like the opacity to be applied to the result of the two loops,

```
  \begin{scope}[transparency group,opacity=.2]
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \k using 0.75-\i] in {0,0.25,...,4.75}
    {
      \foreach \j in {-4,-3.75,...,\k}
      \filldraw[draw=black, fill=blue] (0,\j) rectangle (0.25,\j+0.25);
    }
  \end{scope}
```

[image: consistent opacity using transparency group]

But you may also be hoping for some other image I've not managed to guess ;).

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \k using 0.75-\i] in {0,0.25,...,4.75}
{
  \foreach \j in {-4,-3.75,...,\k}
    \filldraw[draw=black, fill=blue,opacity=0.2] (0,\j) rectangle (0.25,\j+0.25);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \k using 0.75-\i] in {0,0.25,...,4.75}
{
  \foreach \j in {-4,-3.75,...,\k}
    \filldraw[draw=black, fill=blue,opacity=0.2] (\i,\j) rectangle (\i+0.25,\j+0.25);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[transparency group,opacity=.2]
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \k using 0.75-\i] in {0,0.25,...,4.75}
    {
      \foreach \j in {-4,-3.75,...,\k}
      \filldraw[draw=black, fill=blue] (0,\j) rectangle (0.25,\j+0.25);
    }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## EDIT

If I wanted the second image (but less a square), I'd do something more like this,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2.5mm,y=2.5mm]
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \k using int(19-\i)] in {0,...,19}
{
  \foreach \j  in {0,...,\k}
    \filldraw[draw=black, fill=blue,opacity=0.2] (\i,\j) rectangle ++(1,1);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: steps in non-graduated blue]

This involves fewer calculations, is easier to understand and will produce a more accurate result (because calculating with decimals introduces imprecision, though the accumulation probably doesn't matter here).

Comment: The second picture is what I was aiming for, with 1 less square in the final column. Thanks for this detailed answer and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @EthanAlwaise No worries. It's always hard to figure out what won't be obvious, but giving the error is a good rule. Often somebody will know what's wrong without having to copy-paste-compile to see. Re. squares, please see edit. I don't know your real use, of course, but, at least for the example, I think you can make this simpler and more efficient.